# Differential equations, What is the 'D' notation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Why is y" + 5y' + 6y written as (D² + 5D + 6)y ?

Is 'D' = dy/dx and 'D²' = d²y/dx²... then if you multiply the whole thing by 'y' how can they be equal ?

Sorry for the stupid question, but without clearing what this means i cannot proceed.

edit : found the anser after googling a bit

Comment: Think of $D$ as a $\dfrac d {dx}$ operator on functions:  $Dy=\dfrac {dy}{dx}$ and $D^2y=\dfrac {d^2y}{dx^2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$D$ isn't "the derivative of $y$", it means "The derivative of", and is applied to whatever it is multiplied with (on the right side). So $Dy$ means "The derivative of $y$", and $D^2y=DDy$ means "The derivative of the derivative of $y$". It doesn't commute with functions ($Dy$ is not the same as $yD$), but otherwise it behaves just like you would expect a letter to behave in algebra.

Answer (score 1):

consider,   y" - y = 0 in the form

(D² - 1)y = 0

In the previous line, D stands for the operation of differentiation. That is, Dy represents the operation of differentiating y, which results in y'. Similarly, D² means to apply the D-operator twice, so that D²y results in y". Thought of as operators, real numbers applied to functions result in multiplication of the function by the number.